# Why does FK constraint exception in a repo's SaveChanges() method persist in another repo with another context?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a try/catch set up like this.

First I try to log a record to our audit_log table.

```
try
{
    AuditLog finalReportIssuedUpdate = new AuditLog
                {
                    AuditId = auditId,
                    MilestoneId = 10,
                    LogText = $"Final Audit Report was issued (modified {DateTime.Now}).",
                    LogReason = reason,
                    LogDt = finalReportIssued,
                    StaffId = staffId,
                    //OfficeId
                    LogEntryDt = DateTime.Now
                };

    _auditLogRepo.Add(finalReportIssuedUpdate);
    _auditLogRepo.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here I get a FK constraint that `AuditID` has to match an `id` in the `Audit` table.

Ok, so now it goes to the catch.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _errorLogRepo.Add(new ErrorLog
                          {
                              ErrorLogMessage = ex.Message,
                              ErrorLogStackTrace = ex.StackTrace,
                              ErrorLogStaffId = staffId,
                              ErrorLogDate = DateTime.Now
                          });
    _errorLogRepo.SaveChanges();
}
```

But now when it goes to the errorLogRepo's `SaveChanges()` method, it is showing me the auditLogRepo's exception again about the FK constraint violation. It won't let me use EF to log the error:(

Here is `AuditLogRepository`:

```
public class AuditLogRepository : IAuditLogRepository
{
        private ApplicationDbContext context;

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides an application database context to the class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ctx"></param>
        public AuditLogRepository(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }

        public IQueryable<AuditLog> AuditLogs => context.AuditLogs;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the AuditLog record matching the selected id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Id of the record to retrieve.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public AuditLog Get(int id)
        {
            AuditLog auditLog = context.AuditLogs.Find(id);
            return auditLog;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts a new audit log record into the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="auditLog"></param>
        public void Add(AuditLog auditLog)
        {
            context.AuditLogs.Add(auditLog);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the changes to the AuditLog record
        /// </summary>
        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Here is errorLogRepo:

```
public class ErrorLogRepo : IErrorLogRepo
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context;

    public ErrorLogRepo(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    public IQueryable<ErrorLog> ErrorLogs => context.ErrorLogs;

    public void Add(ErrorLog errorLog)
    {
        context.ErrorLogs.Add(errorLog);
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Nothing special.

Two repos, two contexts. Why is this not letting me use a second repo in the catch right after an exception?

Comment: Most likely the case is Two repos - **One** context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems both of your repositories rely on the same ApplicationDbContext instance.

So when you call the `SaveChanges()` method on either one of those, it actually calls the `SaveChanges` on the underlying context instance, which is shared, and results in an effort to insert both entities into the underlying storage. Hence the error.

There are two options you can go with from here:
1. In the catch block remove the added `AuditLog` record from the repo, before adding the error log.
2. Have two separate instances of `ApplicaitonDbContext` for two repository classes. This is heavy, so I would suggest option #1